# "tmp" couldn't be removed because you don't have permission to access it

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator, devops

While trying to invoke simulator on macincloud server, I am getting the following error.

[image: mac_tmp_could_not_be_removed]

Steps tried by me:
1) Searched for "tmp" directories on my mac machine, but do not see any. 
2) Tried to reset simulator, but after the confirmation screen (which asks whether or not to reset simulator), it throws the same error as mentioned above.

The permissions on the Xcode directory is as follows:

[image]

From the **Activity Monitor** I searched for the processes related to *simulator* and using the logs I could figure out the location of "tmp" folder, trying to delete which simulator is throwing the error. When I am trying to remove the folder manually, I get below error:

[image]

So which means root user is required to delete the "tmp" directory. Since I am using a non-root user to invoke the simulator, what can I do to overcome this issue?

EDIT: 
I have elevated the permissions for my account recursively on my home and I have the following permissions:

[image: my_permissions]

After changing the permissions when I try to delete contents of tmp directory I get this error:
[image]

So I think there is something wrong with the permissions that I have provided on the folders/files under my home directory.

Comment: change permissions of complete Xcode folder in application, search google about how to change permission

Comment: It already has all the permissions on the Xcode directory for the user with which I am executing this command. Edited my post to add the permissions

Comment: Just found out that even though I have the required permissions, I am unable to delete the "tmp" directory using the user with which I am invoking the simulator.  I have removed the directory as of now using _sudo_ and this seems resolve the issue (I am not getting the same error for now), but this does not seem to be a solution so far, it's just a workaround.

Comment: How did you get into this state in the first place?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia , not sure if you are asking for some steps here because I do not recall doing anything in specific that led to this issue. I am still facing this issue and I only have a workaround and no solution so far.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for reproduction steps.  You can use 'sudo' to elevate your permissions to delete those files that are not owned by you.

Comment: Hi, honestly I am not sure what led to this issue. About elevation of permissions to grant me delete rights, I've already done that, but still I am unable to delete the tmp folder. I am posting the permissions for my account in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I am describing a solution [here](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2015/10/fixing-the-simulators/) - basically you have to remove the defunct simulator in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` and recreate it.

The fine [snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot) by Felix Krause - which I also explain how to use in this article - helps you to completely reset your simulators to a pristine state.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue in iPhone 6 Simulator (iOS 9.0).
Please check whether all the simulators having this issue or particular simulator.

I have re created the iPhone 6 simulator in the Xcode -> Window -> Organiser. The newly created simulator works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase it helps others, I think I managed to get in to this state by stopping the build when stopped at a breakpoint (whilst it was paused on the breakpoint I changed my CoreData data model which may have played a part). It's the first time it's happened to me, I just closed the simulator fully and re-run the code (obviously crashed due to the model change as I'm not merging), after it crashed it allowed me to reset the simulator so maybe it locks up during model changes? Just a guess though but thought I would add the steps it took me to create it as it literally just happened.